# axios-cookiejar-support does not support for use with other http(s).Agent

Tags: node.js, rest, https, axios

My code is

```
const axios = require('axios')
const https = require('https');

const axiosCookieJarSupport = require("axios-cookiejar-support");
const tough = require("tough-cookie");

const HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata.streaming=true; charset=utf-8',
    Accept: 'application/json; odata.metadata=none, text/plain',
    'TM1-SessionContext': '----',
    'User-Agent': '----'
  }
  
this.http = axios.create({
   headers: HEADERS,
   withCredentials: true,
   httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
})
        
axiosCookieJarSupport.wrapper(this.http)
this.http.defaults.jar = new tough.CookieJar()
this.http.defaults.baseURL = this.baseUrl
    
// Then other things but that doesn't matter
```

But when i run that i got this error :

```
Error: axios-cookiejar-support does not support for use with other http(s).Agent.
    at requestInterceptor (C:\node_modules\axios-cookiejar-support\dist\index.js:14:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RestService.startSession (C:\main.js:109:29)
```

I guess the problem come from the https agent initialized with https.Agent({})

Maybe it exist the same constructor from axios lib but i didn't find it

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support/issues/426 and https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support/issues/431 have the answers to similar questions

In short, you want to use a custom HTTPS agent `httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })`, but `axios-cookiejar-support` cannot work with it.

Try to use `http-cookie-agent` instead of `axios-cookiejar-support`, something like this:

```js
const { HttpsCookieAgent } = require('http-cookie-agent');

const jar = new tough.CookieJar();
const httpsAgent = new HttpsCookieAgent({
  jar,
  keepAlive: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

this.http = axios.create({
   headers: HEADERS,
   withCredentials: true,
   httpsAgent,
});
        
this.http.defaults.jar = jar;
this.http.defaults.baseURL = this.baseUrl;
```